# Problems converting values in Python

Tags: python

I am learning Python and I have problems with data types convertions.
When I run the program it says: "Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly".
I'm using the latest version of Python by the way.

I am just trying to make basic math operations.

Here's my code:

```
Quantity=input("PLEASE INSERT NUMBERS OF SHIRTS TO BUY:\n")
Tax=0.12

Price = 100*Quantity
Total = Price + Tax
```

Comment: `float(Quantity)` before using it.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Also `Tax` is a float so it can't be added to the Price string without converting it first - `Total = Price + str(Tax)` say

Comment: I just saw the Tax part, just use `quantity= float(input("PLEASE INSERT NUMBERS OF SHIRTS TO BUY:\n"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you read in the input from the user, it is stored in the `Quantity` variable as a string. You need to convert the variable `Quantity` to a float, by using the code below.

```
quantity=input("PLEASE INSERT NUMBERS OF SHIRTS TO BUY:\n")
tax=0.12

price = 100*float(quantity)
total = price + tax
```

NOTE: I changed your variable to begin with a lowercase character. This is common coding practice. Classes usually being with a capital character, variables begin with a lowercase character.

As Zeiss Ikon stated below, the tax calculation is incorrect. I kept it as it to clearly solve the original question. This is fixed in the calculation below

```
total = price * (1.0 + tax)
```

Comment: `100 * Quantity` does not cause a runtime error, it would make Price  equal to 100 repetitions of the the string Quantity

Comment: I was going off what @JoseMiguelCab stated. He said he was receiving a run-time error when trying to run his original code. If it wasn't the statement `100 * Quantity`, what was it?

Comment: Ok the error makes more since now. Can you explain why the error isn't happening when 100 * Quantity line is executed. Is Quantity being converted to an int?

Comment: I assume that's 12% sales tax (or VAT) rather than a flat 12 cents on any amount, right?  So you'd want `total = price * (1.0 + tax)` or, to round to nearest cent, follow with `total = float (int(total * 100 + 0.5))/100`

Comment: Yes @ZeissIkon, I noticed this as well after I posted the answer, although the question that OP asked was asking to solve the error, not fix his math, so I didn't touch on this issue. I suppose I'll edit my Answer to let him know of his fault.

Comment: 100 * Quantity is not causing an error because to is perfectly legal to do `"foo" * 3 -> "foofoofoo"` but what sould `"foo" + 2` output?